# How to collapse to a data frame with minimum int values from a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to get a collapsed data frame, from a list of data frames, with minimum values for each cell based on the same cell across the data frames available in the list.

The example given below has 5 rows and 2 columns. If I run the code shown below on a data frame that has 60,000 rows and 15 columns, it is very slow. I want to determine if there is a more efficient way to solve this problem.

```r
one_df <- data.frame(v1 = c(0,1,2,3,4), v2 = c(5,6,7,8,9))
two_df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,2,3,4), v2 = c(5,6,7,7,8))
my_list <- list(one_df, two_df)
num_rows <- dim(one_df)[1]
num_cols <- dim(one_df)[2]
result_df <- one_df ## The collapsed data frame has the same dimensions as the input data frame
for (num_row in 1:num_rows){
    for (num_col in 1:num_cols){
        result_df[num_row, num_col] <- do.call("min", lapply(my_list, function(x) x[num_row, num_col]))
    }
}
```

The example input is:

```
> my_list
[[1]]
  v1 v2
1  0  5
2  1  6
3  2  7
4  3  8
5  4  9

[[2]]
  v1 v2
1  1  5
2  2  6
3  2  7
4  3  7
5  4  8
```

The expected output for the example is:

```
> result_df
  v1 v2
1  0  5
2  1  6
3  2  7
4  3  7
5  4  8
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
do.call(pmin, my_list)
  v1 v2
1  0  5
2  1  6
3  2  7
4  3  7
5  4  8
```

---

Same as calling

```
pmin(my_list[[1]], my_list[[2]], ..., my_list[[n]])
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(my_list, pmin)
```

---

Also, it may be faster to `unlist` and then do `min` on it

```
my_list1 <- my_list[rep(seq_along(my_list), each = 1e5)]
system.time(tapply(unlist(my_list1), rep(1:10,  length(my_list1), FUN = min)))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.334   0.013   0.348 

system.time(reduce(my_list1, pmin))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 29.665   0.141  29.729 
system.time(do.call(pmin, my_list1))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 25.371   0.109  25.450
```